# Что означает параметр random_state в sklearn.manifold.TSNE и других классах SciKit-Learn?

Tags: python, машинное-обучение, numpy, scikit-learn

Ставил 3 разных значений `random_state`, это: `(None, 0, 1)`.

Так и не понял, в чем заключается суть этого метода. Читал документацию, ответ на сайте, но так и не понял.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28064634/random-state-pseudo-random-numberin-scikit-learn

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Суть параметра `random_state` (во всех функциях и методах из `SciKit-Learn`) в воспроизводимых случайных значениях. Т.е. если явно задать значение `random_state` отличным от `None` - то генерируемые псевдослучайные величины будут иметь одни и те же значения при каждом вызове.

Пример:

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: np.random.seed(31415)

In [3]: np.random.randint(10, size=(5,5))
Out[3]:
array([[7, 3, 5, 8, 2],
       [6, 6, 3, 5, 6],
       [0, 0, 8, 3, 6],
       [1, 6, 8, 5, 1],
       [4, 6, 9, 2, 7]])

In [4]: np.random.seed(31415)

In [5]: np.random.randint(10, size=(5,5))
Out[5]:
array([[7, 3, 5, 8, 2],
       [6, 6, 3, 5, 6],
       [0, 0, 8, 3, 6],
       [1, 6, 8, 5, 1],
       [4, 6, 9, 2, 7]])

In [6]: np.random.seed(31415)

In [7]: np.random.randint(10, size=(5,5))
Out[7]:
array([[7, 3, 5, 8, 2],
       [6, 6, 3, 5, 6],
       [0, 0, 8, 3, 6],
       [1, 6, 8, 5, 1],
       [4, 6, 9, 2, 7]])
```

PS если вы запустите данный код на вашем компьютере - вы получите те же самые значения в матрицах.

> Зачем это нужно?

В задачах машинного обучения и не только часто используется генератор псевдослучайных чисел для инициализации различных параметров, весов в нейросетях, случайного разделения дата сета на обучающий и проверочный сеты.

Соответственно если мы хотим сравнить несколько методов или разные наборы параметров, то для честного сравнения надо использовать одинаковые обучающие и проверочные сеты.

Также бывает полезно создать наборы данных случайным, но воспроизводимым способом. Например вы создали несколько различных вычислительных методов и хотите их сравнить или проверить правильность - для этого необходимо использовать одинаковые входные данные.

---

**UPD:** Если задать одинаковое значение `random_state`, то на одинаковых входных данных результат `t-SNE` будет тоже одинаковый:

```
In [120]: from sklearn.manifold import TSNE

In [121]: a = np.random.rand(1000, 50)

In [122]: res1 = TSNE(n_components=2, random_state=123).fit_transform(a)

In [123]: res2 = TSNE(n_components=2, random_state=123).fit_transform(a)

In [124]: res1.sum()
Out[124]: -205.98636

In [125]: res2.sum()
Out[125]: -205.98636

In [126]: res1 == res2
Out[126]:
array([[ True,  True],
       [ True,  True],
       [ True,  True],
       ...,
       [ True,  True],
       [ True,  True],
       [ True,  True]])

In [127]: (res1 == res2).all()
Out[127]: True
```

Answer (score 2):

Так то в ответе MaxU всё правильно, но вообще первопричина тут в том, что `t-sne` по своей природе **случайный** алгоритм. По-русски он называется "**Стохастическое** вложение соседей с t-распределением". Конечно, на визуализации результатов его работы с разным `random_state` (либо с не указанным явно `random_state`), вы вряд ли заметите глазом разницу. Но если будете сравнивать численные результаты работы `t-sne`, то они будут каждый раз **разные**. Ну, если у вас не случай очень малого количества хорошо разделимых данных - тогда результат может быть и одинаковый. В общем случае, если хотите получать от `t-sne` одинаковый результат на одинаковых данных - фиксируйте `random_state`.
Ну и ещё можно дополнить, что далеко не все алгоритмы `SciKit-Learn` и других библиотек машинного обучения имеют элемент случайности, конечно. Но те, которые зависят от случайности, обычно позволяют зафиксировать эту случайность так, чтобы она была воспроизводима.

Comment: при использовании одинакового значения `random_state` и результат будет одинковый - см. UPD в моем ответе ;)

Comment: @MaxU Да я только хотел дополнить, что сам алгоритм tsne по своей природе рандомный, поэтому вообще тут имеет смысл говорить про random_state )