# Что значит seed и на что он влияет?

Tags: python, случайные-числа, keras, tensorflow

```
from numpy.random import seed
seed(42)
import tensorflow
tensorflow.random.set_seed(42)
```

Решил поработать с KerasTuner для автоматической подбора гиперпараметров нейронной сети. Что значит seed и на что он влияет/ здесь как то непонятно коротко описывается, а больше нигде не нахожу.

https://towardsdatascience.com/hyperparameter-tuning-with-keras-tuner-283474fbfbe
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: [связанный вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/858395/211923)

Comment: @MaxU Или даже дубликат )

Comment: @CrazyElf, там все-таки о `random_state` спрашивали)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`seed` инициализирует генератор случайных чисел. Инициализация ГСЧ во всех используемых библиотеках делается для повторяемости результата. Когда вы делаете исследование и куда-то выкладываете результаты бывает важно, чтобы любой мог его повторить и получить те же самые результаты. Если ГСЧ не инициализировать, результаты могут отличаться - ведь многие из используемых в машинном обучении методов по своей природе стохастические (случайные).